# launchArgs in PushPlugin (Cordova and Windows Universal app)

Tags: cordova, push-notification, win-universal-app

I'm trying to develop the Windows Universal App version of an app already developed for Android and iOS. 
I'm using the PushPlugin for notification, but I don't understand where to find the launchArgs parameters sent inside the Toast package.

This is the xml:

```
<toast activationType="background" launch="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;toast&quot;:&quot;param1&quot;:&quot;12345&quot;:&quot;param2&quot;:&quot;67890&quot;}">
        <visual>
            <binding template="ToastGeneric">
                <text id="1">'.$subject.'</text>
                <text id="2">'.$message.'</text>                                        
            </binding>  
        </visual>
    </toast>
```

In the push.on("notification") method I expected to find "data.additionalData.foreground" (if my app is foreground - this works perfectly for Android and iOS), but this property in Windows is always undefined. Where is the error?

Thanks for every suggestion,
bye

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else is having this question, the `launch` string is retrieved from the `data.launchArgs` variable on the client side.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#callback-parameters-2

However, it seems these arguments will be ignored when the app is in foreground, because thie `launch` parameter was intended only to launch the app when it's closed or in the background.